# Ho to get Open Windows(file,program,editor,page) Detail (size, properties, position) in c#

Tags: c#, .net

How to get list of opened files and programes ,properties of files (e.g., Image / Text + Editor / Player), and status of file (e.g. maximized or minimized) if maximized its x-exis and y-axis position 
How it is possible in C#
For example if i am working on Ms.word file, and at the same time i'm using browser and media player, how i can get it

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406888/get-location-and-size-of-all-open-windows-using-net-c) will help you. At least it's a starting point.

Comment: no,its not helpfull .

Comment: I answered your question!

Comment: As this is your first question Check out [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to submit a better question next time. The first will guide you on how and what to ask and the second will guide you with creating some example so we can recreate it to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code helped you

```
var frame = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame)Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content;
if (frame.Content.GetType() == typeof(YourNameWindows))
{
//mean YourNameWindow is open now
   var page = (YourNameWindows)frame.Content;
// you can access all property of opened window
}
```